# find command in unix withe regex

Tags: unix, find

Can someone tell me what this command does : `find ./ -regex ".*"\!*"*"` ?

Comment: Which shell do you use? Is this part of an alias definition?

Answer (score 0):

Guess based on too little information in the question:

This may be part of the definition of an alias like

```
alias f 'find ./ -regex ".*"\!*"*"'
```

for `csh` or `tcsh` which could be called like

```
f some pattern
```

to recursively find files that somehow match the specified pattern.